# Learning Ruby ERB Templates

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, erb

I'm trying to learn Ruby ERB Templates using the following guide:
[Tutorial Link](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/erb/)

I am on the "very simple example" section with the following code:

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= weekday %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

I wanted to run this code to generate an html file so I created a file called

```
testing.html.erb
```

and ran the code with the following command:

```
erb testing.html.erb > new-file.html
```

When I did that through the terminal several errors popped up and the html file that was generated was blank.  Here are the errors that I received:
[image]

I was hoping someone could tell me what i was doing wrong.  Am I forgetting something? Or am I not running the erb command correctly? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what if you add @ symbol to your variable: `@weekday`

Comment: I'll try that and report back to you!

Comment: @LukaszMuzyka I did that and the error went away, but the generated file was still incorrect.  Here is the error: require 'erb' weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A') simple_template = "Today is ." renderer = ERB.new(simple_template) puts output = renderer.result()

Comment: It appears to have done a direct translation rather than a filtered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will run if you pass it to ruby. That is initiate it with this:

```
ruby testing.html.erb > new-file.html
```

The `erb` command expects to be passed an erb template file and not a piece of ruby code. It sees all the ruby code as just plain text, with just the insertion code `<%= weekday %>` needing to be interpreted as ruby code. So it tries to interpet `weekday` - but as it hasn't been defined it fails.

Try this and I think you may see what's happening:

Change the content of the file 'testing.html.erb' to:

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= Time.now %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

Then look at the output of `erb testing.html.erb`:

> require 'erb'
>
> weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A') simple_template = "Today is
>   2016-10-24 08:40:41 +0100."
>
> renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)

Note that the whole file 'testing.html.erb' is the template.

Now look at the output of `ruby testing.html.erb`

> Today is 2016-10-24 08:42:16 +0100.

Here the template is the content of the variable `simple_template`

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if you send binding to the results method.

```
puts output = renderer.result(binding)
```

more about bindings: [Ruby’s Binding Class (binding objects)](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2014/05/18/rubys-binding-class-binding-objects/)